# Call same function from multiple views

Tags: django

I'd like to be able to call a function from different views in django. For example, say I need to generate a random number from within various views, I don't want to have to have the same 'random number' code repeated in each view - I just want to 'call on a function'.

I'm greatly simplifying the following code for the sake of keeping this question brief:

**views.py**

```
def viewOne(request):
#code for this view, including needing to generate a random number
import random
myrandomnumber = random.randint(1,21)*5


def viewTwo(request):
#code for this view, including needing to generate a random number
import random
myrandomnumber = random.randint(1,21)*5
```

As you can see, I'm using the same code in both views to generate a random number. If I wanted to update how I generate a random number, I'd have to update it in both views.

This is the sort of thing I want to do:

**views.py**

```
def createRandomNumber():
import random
myrandomnumber = random.randint(1,21)*5


def viewOne(request):
#code for this view, including needing to generate a random number
createRandomNumber()

def viewTwo(request):
#code for this view, including needing to generate a random number
createRandomNumber()
```

Thanks very much for any help you can give me

Comment: createRandomNumber function needs to `return myrandomnumber` at the end, and use it like `randnum = createRandomNumber() ` in other views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in-order to this you would need to extract the function such that is would be available to all views that need it. You could for example create a file called `utils.py` in your django app define the function there and import it into the `views.py`

**utils.py**

```
import random

def createRandomNumber():
    return random.randint(1,21)*5
```

**views.py**

```
from utils import createRandomNumber

def viewOne(request):
    createRandomNumber()

def viewTwo(request):
    createRandomNumber()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses! That's sorted it.

Comment: @BenjiA You're welcome, A tip to remember when faced with an issue like this is to remember that the django is python and whats valid in python is valid in django. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the code you want to reuse in a function and call that function wherever needed.

Also, don't use import statements inside functions!

```
#views.py
import random
def createRandomNumber():
    myRandomNumber = random.randint(1,21)*5
    return myRandomNumber


def viewOne(request):
#code for this view, including needing to generate a random number
    randomNumber = createRandomNumber()

def viewTwo(request):
#code for this view, including needing to generate a random number
    randomNumber = createRandomNumber()
```

If you need to use that piece of code in different files use an import statement. So assuming you are working with a file in the same directory as your views.py just add

```
from .views import createRandomNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing with the random number, this logic might be better in a model or manager (E.g. selecting a random instance).  That might mean you only need it one place, or you may still want to separate it out into a separate util function.